# Printing an Array in Bootstrap

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I have a multidimensional array.

I use PHP & Bootstrap, currently creating some data structures for my application.

I have used `var_dump(), print_r(), echo ''`, and tried wrapping the array in `<pre></pre>`, but all I get is an inline version of my array.

My current output is:

[image: inline array print using print_r]

I want it to output like the following image:

[image: nice and tidy, visual representation of an array]

How can I get my array to output such as the latter image using the components in Bootstrap?

Comment: Something like Krumo ? http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you use pre tag ?

You should use the `<pre>` html tag to display var_dump output :

```
<pre><?php var_dump($arr); ?></pre>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#code